# Black screen/Distorted image on screen when laptop lid open Ubuntu 15.04 GDM (No any previous answer helped me)

Tags: 14.04, gnome, 15.04, suspend, gdm

I get black screen or distorted image when i reopen my laptop lid.
I am using **Ubuntu 15.04 Gnome** version official download.
My laptop Lenovo Z-5070 &  also i get nothing when i pressed CTRL + ALT + F1.I **tried every answers posted on similar post** but nothing worked for me.
I even **used Mate version** but still the same problem, and also tried fresh install again but still the same.